# Can you retrive a specific marked version for an entire SOLUTION?

Tags: tfs

I'm extremely new to TS and it's not apparent to me. It's seems to me that it must be in there. Could someone please point out how to go about marking a whole solution with a version number or label and then retrieving that specific version back from the repository?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the label isn't the easiest thing to find. You can get to it by right clicking on the folder containing your solution file in the Source Control Explorer window (which you can get to by double-clicking on the Source Control node in Team Explorer).  When you apply the label, apply it to the folder containing the things you want included in the label.  Then ensure that the next screen shows you the contents of that folder (i.e. all the files you want to label)

In TFS a label is a bit like a tag.  It is actually something that can be edited and you can have files of different versions included in it if you really needed to.

There is also the concept of "Changesets" in TFS.  A changeset is a number that always increments on a particular server (or Project Collection in TFS2010).  The number represents a unique point in time for that server instance.

To get the files from a particular version, in Solution Explorer right click on your solution and do "Get Specific Version..."  In the Version group box you can change the type from the default Latest Version to specifing the Changeset, Date or Label if you want to get a version from an older point in time.

Hope that helps.

Martin.

Comment: When I specify that I want to "Get a Label", it prompts me for the Label name, let's me browse and search for a label, all very cool, but when I find it, it seems not to let me click on it so it will be carried ocver to the previous screen where teh Label name is required. Hitting Close does not select it and double clicking on it brings up another screen where I can edit what files are affected by the label.
So I seemed to be forced to hit the close button and manually type in the label name. Obviously, it's not a show-stopper but I'd like to know if I am missing something. ty for your help!